# High CPU utilization when downloading files

Tags: performance, http, erlang, elixir

When downloading files via HTTP using Erlang's `httpc`, CPU utilization is much higher than with curl or wget, for instance. The code I'm using to measure the download speed can be seen at the bottom of this post.

The high CPU utilization is problematic especially on low-end devices. I'm running Erlang on an ARM-SoC which is only slightly more powerful than the first Raspberry PI, and this piece of code results in 100% CPU utilization and a download speed of only 6.1 MiB/s.  With curl and wget, CPU utilization stays slightly below 100% and it manages to almost fully utilize the network interface
(10.7 MiB/s or 85.6 MBit/s on a 100 MBit/s network interface).

I tried using other HTTP libraries including ibrowse and hackney, but the same issue persists. My guess is that it has to do with Erlang's socket performance, but I could be wrong.  So my question is, what exactly is responsible for those slow download speeds, and are there any workarounds for it? I know of libraries like https://github.com/puzza007/katipo which use libcurl and therefore probably won't have the same issue, but I would prefer not to use any libraries that make use of NIFs.

```
defmodule DownloadPerformanceTest do
  @testfile 'http://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin'
  @filesize 104857600
  @save_to '/dev/null'

  def test() do
    Application.start(:inets)
    then = :erlang.system_time(:micro_seconds)
    {:ok, :saved_to_file} = :httpc.request(:get, {@testfile, []}, [], [{:stream, @save_to}])
    now = :erlang.system_time(:micro_seconds)
    diff = now - then
    bw = bandwidth_to_human_readable(@filesize, diff)
    IO.puts "Download took #{:erlang.trunc(diff / 1_000_000)} seconds, average speed: #{bw}"
  end

  defp bandwidth_to_human_readable(bytes, microseconds) do
    bytes_per_second = bytes / (microseconds / 1000000)
    exponent = :erlang.trunc(:math.log2(bytes_per_second) / :math.log2(1024))
    prefix = case exponent do
               0 -> {:ok, ""}
               1 -> {:ok, "Ki"}
               2 -> {:ok, "Mi"}
               3 -> {:ok, "Gi"}
               4 -> {:ok, "Ti"}
               5 -> {:ok, "Pi"}
               6 -> {:ok, "Ei"}
               7 -> {:ok, "Zi"}
               8 -> {:ok, "Yi"}
               _ -> {:error, :too_large}
             end
    case prefix do
      {:ok, prefix} ->
        quantity = Float.round(bytes_per_second / :math.pow(1024, exponent), 2)
        unit = "#{prefix}B/s"
        "#{quantity} #{unit}"
      {:error, :too_large} ->
        "#{bytes_per_second} B/s"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this with just a socket operation? I've worked with httpc enough to find that there are a few idiosyncrasies with it -- but I don't know what would be causing high CPU usage on http downloads. In my experience Erlang's socket performance has been *very* good, even on constrained hardware, but I nearly always write pure socket processes, not using other protocol libs, so I have no idea if there is any inefficient munging of HTTP data going on (maybe HTTP chunks and headers and whatnot are disassembled in relatively expensive way?).

Comment: @zxq9 indeed, using :gen_tcp directly allows me to download with 9.81 MiB/s, compared to 10.5 MiB/s with curl. I'd still prefer to use a proper HTTP library rather than reinventing the wheel, but it seems almost all well-maintained libraries are based either on hackney, or ibrowse.

Comment: In the Erlang world we've only recently really started caring about HTTP and actually, that's really just a few places -- much Erlang work is generally unconnected with the web, and that extends to the culture as well. For that reason we've never really gotten deep into native Erlang web libraries or XML parsing or the madness that is HTML parsing. I imagine that probably also goes for native parsing of HTTP headers, chunking, etc. as *strings* instead of flipping between binaries and atoms and binary-to-string casting, etc.

Comment: I've written one-off HTTP clients and servers a number of times, actually. Its one of those areas where writing it in Erlang is so easy that you do it once and forget that it used to be a problem -- and then never package it as a lib. Deployment is the same sort of issue: the runtime and environment already handle Docker-type issues, so we forget these are problems for which people expect packaged solutions. Same with sockets. Most folks don't know socket programming, so HTTP is (ab)used all over, but for us it is easier to program binary protocols on sockets than to handle HTTP, etc.

Comment: Is `hackney` just as slow as `httpc` in your tests? I'd have expected it to be faster as it uses binaries instead of strings almost everywhere AFAIK.

Comment: @Dogbert "Binaries instead of strings" is a CPU pessimization and a space optimization. The CPU penalty on text parsing of binaries can be significant. This is usually a reasonable tradeoff, especially in a highly parallel environment where lots of string data chunks may be in memory at once. For HTTP chunk handling on a very limited processor (or doing lots in parallel) it may become a CPU issue. Accessing "car" and "cdr", and *Prepend* ("cons") on lists is *fast* (so is `lists:reverse/1`), arbitrary chunk *append* on binaries is *fast*, and the reverse of either is *slow*.

Comment: @Dogbert In my tests, hackney is even slower: https://github.com/nroi/download_performance_test
Of course, it could also be due to my implementation rather than any inefficiencies inherent to hackney.

Comment: Katipo doesn't use a NIF. Instead it uses an external port program that it communicates with via a pipe. This was done for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the [benchmark](https://github.com/nroi/download_performance_test), three clear issues, I am able ascertain

- You are using a remote resource which is effected by externalities making benchmark numbers. Hence for testing, I changed to local resource
- Secondly, except for hackney, none of the other libraries stream the payload to file. Although saving to `/dev/null`, the file saving has a cost.
- Test needs to be run more than once (may be three times)

Once, I removed save action in `download_loop_hackney()`, hackney is the fastest

```
defp download_loop_hackney(client, file) do
    case :hackney.stream_body(client) do
      {:ok, _result} ->

        #IO.binwrite(file, result)
        download_loop_hackney(client, file)
      :done ->
        :ok = File.close(file)
    end
  end
```

The benchmark numbers are thus

```
download_http: download took 0 seconds, average speed: 211.05 MiB/s
download_ibrowse: download took 0 seconds, average speed: 223.15 MiB/s
download_hackney: download took 0 seconds, average speed: 295.83 MiB/s
download_tcp: download took 0 seconds, average speed: 595.84 MiB/s
```

Comment: Good point about the overhead resulting from saving to `/dev/null`, although it's only `download_tcp` that doesn't not store the content. Judging by the download speeds you have obtained, I assume by "local resource" you mean the file was downloaded from localhost. This means the loopback device rather than a real network interface was used. This is not what I wanted to measure because the high CPU utilization is imposed by using the network device.